# Creating a specific custom route in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have several levels of nested routing.

```
 resources :departments do
  resources :tasks do
    collection do
      get "report" => "tasks#report"
    end
 end
```

This a piece of it.

What I am attempting to do is create a custom route for a report.html.erb file. However, this route creates the path /department/:id/tasks/report

I would like to create the path /department/:id/tasks/:id/report

Is this possible? I considered creating a new controller and model for report but this seems to be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
resources :departments do
  resources :tasks do
    member do
      get "report" => "tasks#report"
    end
  end
end
```

or just:

```
resources :departments do
  resources :tasks do
    get "report" => "tasks#report", :on => :member
  end
end
```